# SQL Add empty rows in a Details Table per each Record in a Master Table - Modified Solution

Tags: sql-server

I need to add empty rows to a SQL SELECT statement in such a way that the result is in multiples of 10, meaning if there are 8 rows in a Tables, 2 empty Rows should be added so that the select statement has 10 rows and if there are say 16 rows in a Table, 4 empty rows should be added so that the select statement has 20 rows etc, etc. In short at all times the rows selected must be 10,20,30,40, etc, etc

At the same time it must work in a Master/Details scenario as follows: Assuming there are two records in a Master Table as follows:

```
MasterID
1
2
```

And assuming the following records in a Details Table:

```
ID  MasterID    DetailsDescription
1      1        XXXXX
2      1        XXXXX
3      1        XXXXX
4      1        XXXXX
5      1        XXXXX
6      1        XXXXX
7      2        XXXX
8      2        XXXX
9      2        XXXX
10     2        XXXX
11     2        XXXX
12     2        XXXX
13     2        XXXX
14     2        XXXX
```

I want the result to be:

```
ID  MasterID    DetailsDescription
1      1        XXXXX
2      1        XXXXX
3      1        XXXXX
4      1        XXXXX
5      1        XXXXX
6      1        XXXXX
       1        NULL
       1        NULL
       1        NULL
       1        NULL
7      2        XXXX
8      2        XXXX
9      2        XXXX
10     2        XXXX
11     2        XXXX
12     2        XXXX
13     2        XXXX
14     2        XXXX
       2        NULL
       2        NULL
```

In such a way that for Master Record 1 there must be 10 records selected in the Details Table (i.e. with 4 empty rows added since there are only 6 records in the Details Table linked to Master Record 1) and similarly for Master Record 2 10 rows should be selected in the Details Table (i.e 2 empty rows added since there are 8 rows in the Details Table linked to Master Record 2) etc,etc,etc.

I then got an answer which works fine EXCEPT that it is very slow with large data

```
DECLARE @MasterTable TABLE(MasterID INT)
INSERT INTO @MasterTable
VALUES(1),(2)

DECLARE @DetailsTable TABLE (ID INT, MasterID INT, _Text NVARCHAR(255)) 
DECLARE @X INT=1
WHILE @X <7 
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @DetailsTable VALUES (@X,1, 'XXXXX') 
    SET @X+=1 
END 

SET @X=1
WHILE @X <9 
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @DetailsTable VALUES (@X, 2, 'XXXXX') 
    SET @X+=1 
END 

DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (M_ID INT)
DECLARE @ID INT
INSERT @TEMP SELECT DISTINCT MasterID FROM @MASTERTABLE
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @TEMP) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 M_ID FROM @TEMP)
    INSERT @DETAILSTABLE  
     SELECT TOP (10 - ISNULL(NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  @DETAILSTABLE WHERE MASTERID = @ID) % 10, 0), 10))     
    (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @DETAILSTABLE WHERE MasterID = @ID)+n, @ID, NULL     
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) A(n)
    DELETE @TEMP WHERE M_ID = @ID
END

SELECT * FROM @DETAILSTABLE ORDER BY MasterID, ID
```

The solution I am told would be not to use a WHILE statement but rather use a CTE. This is where I am stack.

Kindly modify the answer so that it uses a CTE or any other fast option as opposed to the one I have now.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing but a loop is definitely not the way to go. Neither is a cte. You should use a numbers or tally table for this type thing. Here is a great article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: I have gone through the link above and still I cannot figure out how to use a Tally Table in this case

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little difficult because you have to some math and oddball things to determine how many rows you need for each group. Before I show my code I need to show you how I keep a tally table on my system. I use a view that requires no reads. It is super crazy fast.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now that we have the view we need to have a table with some sample data. I modified your sample so it is more clear what each row is.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , MasterID int
    , DetailsDescription varchar(10)
)

insert @Something values
(1, 1, 'X1')
, (2, 1, 'X2')
, (3, 1, 'X3')
, (4, 1, 'X4')
, (5, 1, 'X5')
, (6, 1, 'X6')
, (7, 2, 'Y1')
, (8, 2, 'Y2')
, (9, 2, 'Y3')
, (10, 2, 'Y4')
, (11, 2, 'Y5')
, (12, 2, 'Y6')
, (13, 2, 'Y7')
, (14, 2, 'Y8')
, (15, 2, 'Y9')
, (16, 2, 'Y10')
, (17, 2, 'Y11')
, (18, 2, 'Y12')
;
```

Last but not least is the code for generating your desired output. I broke this into three CTEs to demonstrate the steps required for this. You could simplify this a bit if you want. I included some relevant comments in the code that should explain how this works.

```
with GroupNumbers as
(
    select MasterID
        , floor((count(*) + 9) / 10) * 10 as Row_Count --this is how we calculate the number of rows for the group.
    from @Something s
    group by MasterID
)
, BaseRows as --this gets the number of rows for each group
(
    select *
    from GroupNumbers gn
    join cteTally t on t.N <= gn.Row_Count
)
, NumberedRows as --using this in case there are gaps in ID so the numbering is consistent
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MasterID order by ID)
    from @Something
)

select *
from BaseRows br
left join NumberedRows nr on nr.MasterID = br.MasterID and nr.RowNum = br.N
order by br.MasterID
    , br.N
```

Comment: If this works you should consider marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sean answer works. But when I try to run it as a script from within VB I get: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.**. Here is the script:

```
    Dim MyAdapter As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim str As String = 
    "   create View [dbo].[cteTally] as " & _
    "       " & _
    "   WITH    " & _
    "       E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)), " & _
    "       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),    " & _
    "       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),    " & _
    "       cteTally(N) AS  " & _
    "       (   " & _
    "           SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4  " & _
    "       )   " & _
    "   select N from cteTally  " & _
    "   GO  " & _
    "       " & _
    "   declare @Something table    " & _
    "   (   " & _
    "       ID int  " & _
    "       , MasterID int  " & _
    "       , DetailsDescription varchar(10)    " & _
    "   )   " & _
    "       " & _
    "   insert @Something values    " & _
    "   (1, 1, 'X1')    " & _
    "   , (2, 1, 'X2')  " & _
    "   , (3, 1, 'X3')  " & _
    "   , (4, 1, 'X4')  " & _
    "   , (5, 1, 'X5')  " & _
    "   , (6, 1, 'X6')  " & _
    "   , (7, 2, 'Y1')  " & _
    "   , (8, 2, 'Y2')  " & _
    "   , (9, 2, 'Y3')  " & _
    "   , (10, 2, 'Y4') " & _
    "   , (11, 2, 'Y5') " & _
    "   , (12, 2, 'Y6') " & _
    "   , (13, 2, 'Y7') " & _
    "   , (14, 2, 'Y8') " & _
    "   , (15, 2, 'Y9') " & _
    "   , (16, 2, 'Y10')    " & _
    "   , (17, 2, 'Y11')    " & _
    "   , (18, 2, 'Y12')    " & _
    "   ;   " & _
    "       " & _
    "   with GroupNumbers as    " & _
    "   (   " & _
    "       select MasterID " & _
    "           , floor((count(*) + 9) / 10) * 10 as Row_Count  " & _
    "       from @Something s   " & _
    "       group by MasterID   " & _
    "   )   " & _
    "   , BaseRows as   " & _
    "   (   " & _
    "       select *    " & _
    "       from GroupNumbers gn    " & _
    "       join cteTally t on t.N <= gn.Row_Count  " & _
    "   )   " & _
    "   , NumberedRows as   " & _
    "   (   " & _
    "       select *    " & _
    "           , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MasterID order by ID) " & _
    "       from @Something " & _
    "   )   " & _
    "       " & _
    "   select *    " & _
    "   from BaseRows br    " & _
    "   left join NumberedRows nr on nr.MasterID = br.MasterID and nr.RowNum = br.N " & _
    "   order by br.MasterID    " & _
    "       , br.N  " & _
    "       " & _
    "       "


    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myConnectionString)
    command.CommandText = str

    command.CommandTimeout = 0
    MyAdapter.SelectCommand = command

    Dim MyDataSet = New DataSet
    MyAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "Report")
```

Comment: You missed the point. The view should already be on your system. And the table variables and such are to generate some data to work to demonstrate how to solve this.